# Assigning turtle breeds in NetLogo moving probabilities and links

Tags: netlogo

I'm fairly new to programming and NetLogo. 
I would greatly appreciate any help on this!

Basically I have two breeds of turtles in NetLogo. 
The first breed of turtles is initially in a square formation in the centre.

The other breed is randomly dispersed throughout the world. 
My objective is to assign the first breed of turtles in the square a probability that they will move away from themselves (maybe using neighbors? and links?) and also the other breed a probability that it will join onto (maybe with a link?) the first breed, forming a link between the two?

After a long time the two breeds of turtles will basically be randomly distributed throughout the world.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You may be trying to learn too much all at once by writing a big program all at once. To get help, you'll need to post a specific question about a specific coding challenge you are facing — not just a broad description of your overall goal. With only the information given, there isn't much we can say besides: Go for it! And when you run in trouble, show your code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: What Seth said. Also, it might help you to define (in human language) what behavior you want, without referring to NetLogo code. Once you have a clear idea of the rules or behavior, you can ask specific questions about how to achieve it.

Comment: I think this was one of my introduction to net logo exercises, and I recall using `in-cone` to check whether there was any turtles ahead, if so, I'd turn around randomly and check again. If there was no turtles I'd go `forward` a random amount of units until getting out of the square.